# Iterating in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add objects in an array, each array has multiple fields like email and name. The following is how the array looks like. I want to add it to another array.

```
result = [
  {
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "abc"
  },
  {
    "email": "def@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "def"
  }
]
```

The following is the logic I'm trying to apply.

```
var userEmail = ""
var users = [];
var newUser = {'email' : "", 'name' : "", 'type' : 'to'};

for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
   userEmail = result[i].email
   //console.log(userEmail);
   newUser.email = result[i].email;
   newUser.name = result[i].firstName; 
   users.push(newUser);
  }
```

My expected output is this

```
users = [ { email: 'abc@gmail.com', name: 'abc' },
  { email: 'def@gmail.com', name: 'def' } ]
```

But the output I'm getting is this

```
[ { email: 'abc@gmail.com', name: 'abc' },
  { email: 'abc@gmail.com', name: 'abc' } ]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're repeatedly updating a *single* object with the new values, instead of creating a *new* object in each iteration.  You should have created `var newUser = {};` *inside* the loop.

That said, it would be better to use `.map` which is the standard function to transmute an array into another array:

```
var users = result.map(function(r) {
    return { email: r.email, name: r.firstName, type: 'to' };
});
```

or in ES6 syntax:

```
let users = result.map(r => ({ email: r.email, name: r.firstName, type: 'to' }));
```

Comment: How do I create a new object in each iteration

Comment: that is it! I think, some more description might be required on this.

Comment: Or by using [destructuring](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html): `result.map(({email, firstName}) => ({email, name: firstName}))`. Take away in general is to use the higher order functions (`map`, `filter`, `reduce`, ...) to avoid error prone for iterations when transforming data from one form into another.

Comment: @dotcs I'm not sure that the destructuring helps much in this particular case

Answer (score 1):

You were running into problems with your `newUsers` object. Since it is an object you are just adding a reference to this object to the `users` array. When you are changing it agin in the second iteration you are also mutating the original reference. The below snippet should fix the problem.

```js
var userEmail = ""
var users = [];
                          
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
   users.push({
     email: result[i].email,
     name: result[i].firstName,
     type: 'to'
   });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var result = [
  {
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "abc"
  },
  {
    "email": "def@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "def"
  }
];

users = [];

result.forEach(function(obj){
    var newUser = {};
    newUser.email = obj.email;
    newUser.name = obj.firstName
    users.push(newUser)
})

console.log(users)
```

Comment: What  is wrong with this approch. can anyone explain this ?

Comment: you've used `.forEach / push` when you should have used `.map`